# Extension method that writes to a stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream

```
public static void streamReport(this Report report, Stream stream)
{
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
       //some logic that calls streamWrite.Write()
       streamWriter.Flush();
    }
    //Should "return stream;" here ?         
}
```

I am writing an extension method to an object in which I would like to transform to a CSV which is generated and returned to a client (web).

My questions are:

1. Should I return `stream` (change `void` to `Stream`) ?
2. Should I use the `out` keyword in before the `Stream` parameter ? Is this a common way to let the caller know the parameter will be changed ?
3. Should I change the method to generate a new stream (and not accept one) and trust the user to `Dispose` it ?
4. Should I pass `StreamWriter` instead of `Stream` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your questions imply that you might not be quite aware of how streams or references work in C#.

- You pass in a reference to a `Stream`
- You create a `StreamWriter` which writes to that `Stream`
- This will automatically make changes visible to anyone holding a reference to the same `Stream`.

Therefor there is no need to try and return the `Stream` in any way from the method to make the changes visible to the caller - you just need to write to it. This is at least how I interpret your questions.

However there is a catch in your implementation: disposing the `StreamWriter` will automatically close the underlying `Stream` which I find hugely annoying at times.  [Only since .NET 4.5 there is a constructor for `StreamWriter` which allows you to leave the `Stream` open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712853%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So right now your extension method will close the `Stream` which I guess is not the intention. Your only option to avoid that is to use .NET 4.5 or do not wrap the `StreamWriter` in a `using` statement.

Comment: Nice comment, I am using `4.5.1`, will switch for this constructor.

Answer (score 4):

1. Do you *need* the `Stream` reference in outer scope? I doubt it. After all, you already pass this same reference as parameter, so you should *already have* it. Also pay attention to `StreamWriter`. When you dispose it in `using` block - you dispose the underlying stream as well. Accessing it later on will lead to exceptions.
2. No, you should not, if all you do is writing to the given stream. `out` implies, that you will assign a new value to passed reference parameter (meaning you will call `stream = new FileStream()` at some point or something). Which is not the case apparently.
3. It depends on use cases. I guess the best approach is to create multiple methods to cover them all. For example you can create another method, which would accept `string` (file path) instead of a `Stream`. And another, which would accept a `StreamWriter`.

Also, you should use verbs as method names. `Write(...)` or `WriteCsv(...)` for example. Not `streamReport`.

Comment: Thanks, I added a question.. due to the point you mention in 1